# How to represent software code for code generation / automatic programming? How to integrate procedural and declarative knowledge?

Tags: logic, software-engineering, knowledge-representation, code-generation, modal-logic

I am learning about deontic logics and there I can make the following inferences: `If A then there is **duty to create an entity of class C**`, `If B then there is **duty to assign value 5 to the attribute c.a**`, `if A and B then **the computation D should be executed**`. I. e. those deontic logic statements contain the usual propositional variables A, B, C, but they also contain actions - pieces of procedural knowledge, like `create an entity of class C` and so on. The questions are:

- **How do I represent those actions in such manner that they can be used for the code generation/automatic programming?** The simple approach can be to represent them by their content - e.g. by the code in the industrial programming language.
- The goal of such reasoning is to create the syntactical tree of the program from which the source code in the industrial programming language can be read as source file. **How do I represent actions that they can form the syntactical tree?**

I feel that the deontic logic (formalized norms) are enough for generating software code (at least business layer - classes and their behavior), but I am struggling with the consequent end of the inference - how to represent actions/source code?

This may be seen as the more general question as well: formalized norms can be seen as the declarative knowledge and we should create reactive, procedural programs / procedural knowledge from the declarative knowledge - **how to represent procedural knowledge and how to create procedural knowledge from the declarative knowledge?** Are there research efforts to do this and what are keywords for this type of reasearch (so - I can find the already achieved results in Google or journal databases).

Comment: There is promising book Automatic Program Development http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781402065842 in which one article descibes APTS (Abstract Program Transformation System) - system that generates software code from the formal specification. Maybe it is the way to go...

Comment: Maybe this is not trending and I should look for program transformation: there is no generation, there is transformation!

Answer (score 1):

Use some form of metamodelling :

> The outputs are represented as abstract syntax trees (ASTs):

[image: Abstract Syntax Tree]

> and constructed by a decoder with a dynamically-determined modular structure paralleling the structure of the output tree.

[image: meta-model decoder]

**References**

- [Modelling homogeneous generative meta-programming](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06568.pdf)
- [Abstract Syntax Networks for Code Generation and Semantic Parsing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.07535.pdf)
- [Canonical Abstract Syntax Trees](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0601019.pdf)
- [Pattern Reification as the Basis for Description-Driven Systems](https://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0402/0402024.pdf)
- [Metamodelling: State of the Art and Research Challenges](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1409/1409.2359.pdf)
- [DSL development based on target meta-models. Using AST transformations for automating semantic analysis in a textual DSL framework](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0801/0801.1219.pdf)
- [The Machine that Builds Itself:
  How the Strengths of Lisp Family Languages
  Facilitate Building Complex and Flexible
  Bioinformatic Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.02621.pdf)
- [Reasoning About LLVM Code Using Codewalker](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06083.pdf)
- [Foundations of meta-programming](http://users.sussex.ac.uk/~mfb21/publications/mp-slides/slides.pdf)